# Making postition: absolute div the width of remaining space

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a footer that has a position of fixed. The div takes up the entire screen except for the sidebar, which can be collapsed. Setting the div's width to 100% makes it the same with entire viewport width, and because of the sidebar, it goes past the edge of the screen. I would just calculate 100vh - sidebar width, but because it can vary, this is not a viable solution. How could I make it so that the width of the div is not more than the width of the screen? Here is the css:

```
.delete {
  background: #ece4d4;
  border-top: 2px solid var(--primary);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.message {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

And here is what the react component returns:

```
<div className="delete">
  <div className="delete-contents">
    <p className="message">Delete Account</p>
    <p className="sub-message">This action cannot be undone.</p>
    <button onClick={()=> {
      userDelete();
      logout();
      }}>Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is your footer absolute?

Comment: I changed it to fixed but that did not change anything in terms of my issue.

Comment: Is the sidebar also absolute/fixed?

Comment: The sidebar is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Making the footer `fixed` or `absolute` is an issue itself.

Better use flex:

*Click on the footer to hide the navbar
Click on main to make it long*

```js
let navOpen = true;

const nav = document.querySelector('.navbar')
const footer = document.querySelector('.footer')

footer.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav.style.width = navOpen ? '0' : '30%'
  navOpen = !navOpen
})

let mainShort = true;

const main = document.querySelector('.main')

main.addEventListener('click', () => {
  main.textContent = mainShort ? 'main '.repeat(1050) : 'main'
  mainShort = !mainShort
})
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  width: 30%;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  background: purple;
}

.footer {
  height: 5rem;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">nav</nav>
<div class="wrapper">
  <main class="main">main</main>
  <footer class="footer">footer</footer>
</div>
```